# Ubuntu 16.04 hangs at shutdown with '/dev/sda2 xx/yy files xx/yy blocks'

Tags: 16.04, boot, shutdown

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 on an Asus 17.3" Republic of Gamers G752. Full specs: http://www.shophive.com/asus-17-3-republic-of-gamers-g752vt

I've had it for about 2 years and it has worked fine, but since a couple of weeks ago, sometimes when I shut it down, I come back to see that it didn't turn off, and instead its stuck on a black screen saying something like this:

`/dev/sda2 xxxx/yyyy files xxxx/yyyy blocks`

Sometimes it also says `recovering journal` and then there are a couple of lines following that.

What's going on here? How can I fix this?

`$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial`

Edit: Result of `smartctl`:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda2
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-130-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     HGST Travelstar 7K1000
Device Model:     HGST HTS721010A9E630
Serial Number:    JR10004M0GL88E
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000cca 8a8c6a1c4
Firmware Version: JB0OA3J0
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Jul 20 09:57:28 2018 PKT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (   45) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 169) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   119   119   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1117
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   069   069   000    Old_age   Always       -       13880
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1055
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       95
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7071
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   122   122   000    Old_age   Always       -       49 (Min/Max 14/78)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       10
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 10 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 10 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12553 hours (523 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 41 c7 49 50 00  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x005049c7 = 5261767

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 18 48 28 83 f5 40 00      00:04:29.630  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 40 b0 85 f5 40 00      00:04:29.629  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 38 30 85 f5 40 00      00:04:29.629  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 70 84 f5 40 00      00:04:29.629  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 10 d8 84 f5 40 00      00:04:29.629  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 9 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12553 hours (523 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 d1 2f ac b2 02  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x02b2ac2f = 45263919

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 08 98 78 09 5b 40 00      00:03:06.942  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 90 00 ad b2 40 00      00:03:06.932  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 88 00 ac b2 40 00      00:03:06.931  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 ab b2 40 00      00:03:06.930  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 78 10 22 d1 40 00      00:03:06.919  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 8 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12553 hours (523 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 31 cf c8 d1 08  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x08d1c8cf = 147966159

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 b0 38 00 df a2 40 00      00:02:22.727  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 30 00 c8 d1 40 00      00:02:22.712  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 28 40 14 91 40 00      00:02:22.710  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 d0 20 20 32 94 40 00      00:02:22.710  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 18 f0 07 95 40 00      00:02:22.699  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 7 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12553 hours (523 days + 1 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 01 77 14 90 08  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x08901477 = 143660151

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 10 68 00 19 14 40 00      00:00:21.564  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 08 60 68 09 91 40 00      00:00:21.564  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 58 00 d6 f8 40 00      00:00:21.564  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 40 00 d5 f8 40 00      00:00:21.560  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 38 40 af 5a 40 00      00:00:21.554  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 6 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 12522 hours (521 days + 18 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  84 51 21 bf 3b 14 06  Error: ICRC, ABRT at LBA = 0x06143bbf = 101989311

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 a0 e0 3a 14 40 00      11:04:12.653  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 98 e0 39 14 40 00      11:04:12.650  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 90 e8 3d 54 40 00      11:04:12.639  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 20 88 a0 ba 56 40 00      11:04:12.637  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 08 1c 6c 40 00      11:04:12.632  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: The message you are seeing is the results of a `fsck` (file system check).  You should normally only see that message very occasionally (it can be made to check more or less often) except after incomplete/incorrect shutdowns where it should be expected.  I'd be suspicious your hdd/sdd is failing, and I'd boot up a 'live' environment (so it's not using your drive) and check it's health (`smartctl` or your favorite tool).  The tool reads data from the drive electronics, and not drive itself.  It may not be hardware related; but it's what I'd check first.

Comment: @guiverc Is it possible to use smartctl without booting a live env?

Comment: @guiverc Does fsck run if there are any HDD issues detected?

Comment: Yep; it's in `smartmontools`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=smartmontools)  and you'll likely need to install it

Comment: `fsck` I think only runs every 30th boot unless issues are detected (bad shutdown, power loss etc), but this can be changed  (30th is from memory)

Comment: @guiverc Before a few weeks ago I don't think I ever saw that message so I don't know about running every 30 boots, or may be it did run but it shutdown afterwards whereas now it gets stuck & doesn't shut down. I've installed `smartctl`, do I run `smartctl /dev/sda2`?

Comment: @guiverc I've added the result of `smartctl` as an edit , any thoughts?